# R plot_ly: How to add horizontal space in plot area?

Tags: r, r-plotly

I am using `plot_ly` in `R` to create a line chart. By default, the line runs right up to the left and right edges of the plot area. I would like to add some space here, as is done by default in `ggplot`. Does anyone know how to do this with `plot_ly`?

**Reproducible example:**

```
df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), length=50, by='day'),
                 value = rnorm(50))

plot_ly(df, x=~date, y=~value) %>% 
  add_lines(color=I('black')) %>% 
  layout(title = 'plot_ly', plot_bgcolor = 'E9E9E9')

ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=value)) +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle('ggplot')
```

[image]

I would like to add the space shown below with red arrows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `range` in `xaxis` :

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(df, x=~date, y=~value) %>% 
  add_lines(color=I('black')) %>% 
  layout(title = 'plot_ly', plot_bgcolor = 'E9E9E9', 
         xaxis = list(range = c(min(df$date) - 3, max(df$date) + 3)))
```

[image]